# Why is iOS not showing keyboard for input after js has unset a readonly tag?

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I have a `UITextField` in `HTML` form set to readonly. Upon entry javascript should test if the field is currently being edited by someone else, if not the readonly will be set to false and editing of that field is allowed. For this I have used the onFocus() event.

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox but on an iOS device the on-screen keyboard is not showing up. I suspect the Safari Browser on iOS still sees the readonly being active even after the script has set it to false.

It must be possible to make a field readonly again later, so removing it from HTML is not an option.

Is there a way to tell iOS to always show the keyboard even when readonly is set or is this the wrong approach? Maybe triggering it by onFocus() is generally wrong?

javascript part

```
function preCheckField(field,form){
    if(field.readOnly){
    // ses = "<?php echo $session['ukey']; ?>";
    // res = getAccessRequest(field.id, form.id, ses);
    // server side check before entry is skipped for this test
    // assuming entry was allowed the readonly must be unset
        field.readOnly = false;
        dev_div = document.getElementById('dev_message');
        message = (field.id+" can now be modified");
        dev_div.innerHTML = dev_div.innerHTML+"<br>"+message;
        field.focus();
    }
}
```

html part

```
    <form action="#edit.1.product.label" 
        id="input.product.label" 
        method="post" 
        name="product.label" 
        class="form-style">
      Label:<br>
      <input id="1.product.label" 
            name="input" 
            type="text" 
            placeholder="label" 
            onFocus="preCheckField(this,this.form)"
            readonly>
    </form><br>
    DEVELOPER OUTPUT:
    <div id="dev_message">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form element should not already have the focus when changing the readOnly in order to make iOS Safari register the changed status.

On-Screen keyboard will now show as expected.

```
function preCheckField(field, form) {
  if (field.readOnly) {
    field.blur(); // iOS needs this before a change of the readOnly
    // ses = "<?php echo $session['ukey']; ?>';
    // res = getAccessRequest(field.id, form.id, ses);
    // server side check before entry is skipped for this test
    // assuming entry was allowed by getAccessRequest readonly can be unset
    field.readOnly = false;
    dev_div = document.getElementById('dev_message');
    message = (field.id + " can now be modified");
    dev_div.innerHTML = dev_div.innerHTML + "<br>" + message;
    field.focus();
  }
}
```