# How to focus <input> with readOnly attribute in iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, mobile-chrome

I try to use `readOnly` attribute for preventing autofill for an input. I add handler for `focus` event what remove `readOnly` attribute and  handler for `blur` event what add `readOnly` attribute.

But it does not working in any browser in iOS. I found a possible solution to this problem in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56039618/15282905). But this solution does not work when i try focus one `<input>` after another. For example, when i try focus `<input>` after `<button>` all works fine.

Any idea how to fix it?

Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/readonly-for-prevent-autofill-76ecn
[image]

Comment: If you really wanted to prevent autofill then you should have used the `autocomplete="off"` attribute.

Comment: @hacKaTun3s I alway do it in production where it needed. Unfortunately, not all browsers behave according to the spec. For example, in Chrome set `autocomplete="off"` is not enough to prevent autocomplete.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55868247/why-is-ios-not-showing-keyboard-for-input-after-js-has-unset-a-readonly-tag or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59675450/keyboard-doesnt-show-up-when-selecting-input-on-ios-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
 <input ontouchstart="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" readonly>
```

hmmm ... 5 hours